# Perform Multipart upload in GCS in JAVA

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client

I have a file of more than 1GB and want to upload it to Google cloud storage in chunks by using the client library for JAVA. I was able to find multipart upload functions in AWS as well as for AliCloud, but couldn't figure it out for GCS. Read about compose-objects and resumable upload but couldn't find code snippets on how to use the same. How can one do that?

Comment: Is [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-multipart) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

GCS' client library uses GCS' JSON API, however [GCS only supports multipart upload on the XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/multipart-uploads). So at the moment you cannot do multipart upload to GCS using the GCS client library.

#### Multipart upload

You *can* do Multipart upload to GCS using the S3 library, as the GCS XML API is compatible with this. There is a guide to using the S3 library with GCS [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating).  You can also do it directly with HTTP, but that's a lot more work.

#### Resumable upload

If your primary motivation for multipart upload is the reliability of the upload (not having to resend the whole file on connection failure) then resumable upload can also acomplish this. You can do this with the GCS Library's [com.google.cloud.storage.Blob.writer](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/Blob.html#writer-com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.BlobWriteOption...-) method.

#### Parallel upload

If your primary motivation for multipart upload is to be able to upload more than one part at once, for example if you can upload them from different places, then you can do the [parallel upload+compose trick](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads#parallel-composite-uploads). This is regular or resumable uploads done in parallel, and then a final compose operation to join the files together. There is no particular support for this in the library, you will have to use the underlying write and compose operations yourself.